# Travelling to Turkey by ferries

Tags: international-travel, turkey, ferries, greece, egyptian-citizens

I want to ask if I have a valid Schengen with ordinary Egyptian passport I can go to Turkey from Greece by ferries?

Comment: Do you know whether there are ferries from Turkey to Greece these days?

Comment: @Willeke ferrylines.com lists many...

Comment: I think the OP is asking whether an Egyptian passport holder with a Schengen visa can enter Turkey.

Comment: I don't know if there is now but in summer time from Rhodes there is to Fathiye.

Comment: Due to Covid-19 nationals of Egypt (and many other countries) are not currently being allowed entry to Turkey.